# neo4j - Relationship between three nodes

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I'm totally new to `Neo4j` and I'm testing it in these days.
One issue I have with it is how to correctly implement a relationship which involves 3 different nodes using `Spring Data`. Suppose, for example, that I have 3 `@NodeEntity`s: `User`, `Tag` and `TaggableObject`.

As you can argue, a `User` can add a `Tag` to a `TaggableObject`; I model this operation with a `@RelationshipEntity TaggingOperation`.
However, I can't find a simple way to glue the 3 entities inside the relationship. I mean, the obvious choice is to set `@StartNode User tagger` and `@EndNode TaggedObject taggedObject`; but how can I also add the `Tag` to the relationship?

Answer (score 5):

This is called a "hyperedge", I believe, and it's not something that Neo4j supports directly.  You can create an additional node to support it, tough.  So you could have a `TagEvent` node with a schema like so:

```
(:User)-[:PERFORMED]->(:TagEvent)
(:Tag)<-[:USED]-(:TagEvent)
(:TagObject)<-[:TAGGED]-(:TagEvent)
```

Another alternative is to store a foreign key as a property on a relationship or a node.  Obviously that's not very graphy, but if you just need it for reference that might not be a bad solution.  Just remember to not use the internal Neo4j ID as in future versions that may not be dependable.  You should create your own ID for this purpose.

Comment: thanks for your help Brian. I think your `TagEvent` is pretty similar to my `TagOperation`. So, is there a way to specify your schema in `Spring Data Neo4j`, using annotations or so? Are your approach transactional? I mean, how can I assure that when a `User` performs a `TagEvent` using a certaint `Tag` the USED relationship is automatically created?

Comment: Sorry, I've not used Spring Data Neo4j before ;)  I've mainly just worked with Cypher

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway. So, what do you think is the best way to implement it in Java code?

Comment: I'll let somebody else comment.  I haven't written much Java in a long time ;)